# segfault on memcpy once location approaches 100KB

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm attempting to "packetize" a large `mmap()`d file, like so:

```
//numBytes is based on user input
data = static_cast<char*>(mmap((caddr_t)0, numBytes, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, myFile, 0));

int
Sender::Packetize(char* data, int numBytes)
{
    int seqNum = 1;
    int offset = 0;
    size_t totalPacked = 0;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    bool dataRemaining = true;
    while(dataRemaining)
    {
            //MTU = 1460
        size_t payloadSize;
        (numBytes > MTU) ? payloadSize = MTU : payloadSize = numBytes;
        char* payload = (char*)malloc(payloadSize);

        memcpy(payload, data, payloadSize);
        Packet pac = {seqNum, 0, payloadSize, payload}; //Basic struct

        totalPacked += payloadSize;    
        cout << "Packed Bytes: " << payloadSize << endl;
        cout << "Total Packed: " << totalPacked << endl;

        dataMap.insert(pair<int, struct Packet>(seqNum, pac));

        if(numBytes > MTU)
        {
            offset += MTU;
            data = &data[offset];
        }
        else
            dataRemaining = false;

        numBytes -= MTU;
        seqNum++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm working with a 2MB+ file. When I pass in something relatively small for `numBytes` (`5000`), everything appears to work swimmingly. However, if I attempt to pass the entire file (`2533431`), I get segfaults during the `memcpy()`. I've noticed that it appears to be an issue at around 100KB:

```
[.. snip ..]
Packed Bytes: 1460
Total Packed: 99280
Packed Bytes: 1460
Total Packed: 100740
Packed Bytes: 1460
Total Packed: 102200
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, if I attempt to go one chunk smaller (`100740`), I get:

```
[.. snip ..]
Packed Bytes: 1460
Total Packed: 16060
Packed Bytes: 1460
Total Packed: 17520
Packed Bytes: 1460
Total Packed: 18980
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is there some fundamental flaw that I've overlooked, causing my virtual machine to segfault here?

Comment: I would run with some combination of `valgrind` and `strace` (or similar tool), as a quick check.

Comment: `(numBytes > MTU) ? payloadSize = MTU : payloadSize = numBytes;` really should be `payloadSize = (numBytes > MTU) ? MTU : numBytes;` or better yet `payLoadSize = std::min (numBytes, MTU);`.

Comment: Both of your examples segfault - what's the difference between them?

Comment: "VM"? You're running this on a virtual machine?

Comment: VM = Virtual Memory ?

Comment: VM = Virtual Machine, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks, I've updated my local code to reflect this. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this bit of code is the culprit

```
        offset += MTU;
        data = &data[offset];
```

offset starts at 0, data starts at x.

- First time round the loop offset is now 1460, data = data + offset = x + 1460
- Next time round the loop offset is now 2920, data = data + offset = (x + 1460) + 2920 = x + 4380
- Next time round the loop offset is now 4380, data = data + offset = (x + 4380) + 4380 = x + 8790

So `data` is increasing faster than it should. This means that eventually you will be accessing outside of the bounds of `data`.

I recommend removing the `data = &data[offset];` part and just using `data + offset` in the memcpy.

Comment: @MrDuk Note that `valgrind` or some similar tool would have probably helped you spot this.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking `payload` memory. Not `free`ing the memory is causing problem.

**Problem** 
After all memory is exhausted, malloc returns `NULL`.
You should always check the return value of malloc to ensure allocation was successful.
If you try to copy contents into NULL memory, you would get a segfault.

**Solution**
Use `free` at appropriate places to release the memory.
I would suggest allocating MTU size of memory before entering loop and returning it after loop. If MTU is compile time constant, you can better use a static sized array instead of dynamically allocating it.

Because you are using C++, instead of `char* payload = (char*)malloc(payloadSize);`, you can grab memory from some STL container to automatically release the memory.

```
vector<unsigned char> buf(size);
payload = &buf[0];
```

Your memory would be released when buf goes out of scope.

Comment: Definitely a memory leak, but is it likely for malloc to run out of memory after only 2 megabytes?

Comment: @ooga My guess, may be because Sender::Packetize is not the only consumer of dynamic memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I cannot free the memory immediately here (because it's needed elsewhere), but as a test I did attempt to `delete` it, and received the same segfault.

Comment: This time you received segfault becuase you might be accessing dangling pointer through dataMap. It seems you don't have enough memory, you need to keep sending the packet and freeing some memory.

Comment: @MohitJain I don't understand how that's the case - if I explicitly `delete payload` after each loop, I still segfault (at the same spot, and after the same number of bytes).

Comment: Yes because you seem to later access dataMap[idx].second.payload which is [dangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: There are so many things that could be going on. Using some tools will really help you narrow down the problem quickly. For example, first thing to figure out is whether it is the read or the write in memcpy that is causing the segfault.

Comment: @MohitJain No. I don't make it out of this method before the crash occurs. There is no map access before the crash, other than the `insert` you see above.

Comment: You are right, my analysis was insufficient. Correct analysis done and posted by The Dark.